# Match word "A". If "B" is next word, match too

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

Using regex in Python I want to get the word "net" from string and if the word "wt" is the next, get too

Example:

`string = "12 boxes net wt 1.oz  3.6g" #Must returns "net wt"`

`string = "12 boxes net 1.oz  3.6g" #Must returns "net"`

Between "net" and "wt" could be "." "," or spaces

I used this regex but didn't work on the second example

`pat = r'net([,.\s]*?)(wt?)'`

Comment: `(wt?)` matches a group starting with w and optional t. You probably mean `(wt)?` I think

Comment: Use an optional non capturing group `\bnet(?: wt)?\b` https://regex101.com/r/AoSfzN/1

Comment: GREAT!!! Thanks. It worked

Comment: It's not a full answer though if other punctuation can be inbetween. That would be solved through a character class. I'd say put an answer down @Thefourthbird =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you tried `net([,.\s]*?)(wt?)` captures a non greedy match from the character class and then matches a `w` with an optional `t` using the `?` making only the w mandatory and could possible also match `netw` or `net   w`

You could place the character class inside the parenthesis and make that whole part optional placing the `?` after it.

```
\bnet(?:[,. ]wt)?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l4OTXd/1)

Comment: Great. Your solution worked. I changed to detect more than one space, comma or dot

```\bnet(?:[,. ]*wt)?\b```

Comment: An asterisk is maybe not what you want, a plus on the other hand might be.

Comment: Yes, @MarianoAgustinDominguez JvdV is right, the asterix means 0 or more times. Using a plus would be better if there has to be at least a single char from the character class present.

Comment: Great. Actually it may not come with any space between. This text is obtained from an OCR to an image and sometimes OCR doesnt detect any space and the result could be "netwt"